# How to store universities and departments in database in an efficient way?

Tags: database, database-design

I would like to create a web site about universities. My problem is trying to find an efficient way to store departments and universities in tables. For example Koc University has departments Computer Engineering, Business Administration, Economics. But Sabanci University has also Computer Engineering and Economics in its departments. I was thinking that having a table which has university ID's and department ID's but I'm not sure that it is the best idea. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are pretty good that you'll want to differentiate between the departments in each university.  So, for example, the Economics department at Koc is different from the Economics department at Sabanci.  For that you needs two tables:

```
+--------------------
| University        |
+-------------------+
| UniversityId      |
| Name              |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
| Department        |
+-------------------+
| DepartmentId      |
| Name              |
| UniversityId      |
+-------------------+
```

If you only need to reference department type for each university without any extra data about the depoartment, i.e., you only want to know that both Sabanci and Koc have economics departments and nothing else, you can still use the above or you can use this structure:

```
+--------------------
| University        |
+-------------------+
| UniversityId      |
| Name              |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
| Department        |
+-------------------+
| DepartmentId      |
| Name              |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
| UniDept           |
+-------------------+
| UniversityId      |
| DepartmentId      |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Yes there won't be any difference between koc's economy and sabanci's economy. But I'm thinking that I'm going to use a lot of records with design such that almost 100 universities have economics, computer, business which means that there will be 300 records from that. Is that a good solution ?

Comment: There really is no good design that is going to have fewer records than the number of unique departments plus the number of universities. The first solution will have fewer total records but you lose the ability to ask the question: which universities have Business Administration departments (because they might have different names like commerce or business studies). If you accept the design constraint that it's usually considered bad design to store inforamtion in a bridge table like UniDept, then you can't store information about the specific department like number of students, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If same department can be linked with different universities I would do this:
Table Universities, Middle table UniID, DeptID, Table Departments

But if one department is specific to only one university, you remove the middle table and add UniID to Departments.